# Javascript - Get occurence of json array with ESLINT 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I can't set up an algo that counts my occurrences while respecting ESlint's 6 standards in javascript.
My input table is :

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Health",
    "color": "0190fe"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Agriculture",
    "color": "0190fe"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Urban planning",
    "color": "0190fe"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Urban planning",
    "color": "0190fe"
  }
]
```

And i want to get :

> {"Urban planning": 2, "Health": 1, ...}

But that does not work with ESLINT / REACT compilation...

This is my code :

```
    const jsonToIterate = *'MyPreviousInputJson'*
    const names = []
    jsonToIterate.map(item => (names.push(item.name)))

    const count = []
    names.forEach(item => {
      if (count[item]){
        count.push({text: item, value: 1})
      } else {
        count.forEach(function(top){top.text === item ? top.value =+ 1 : null})
      }
    })
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want an object in the end, not an array, so `count` should be `{}`. I also wouldn't use `map` if you're not actually returning anything from the call. You can use `reduce` for this:

```
let counts = topicsSort.reduce((p, c, i, a) => {
   if (!p.hasOwnProperty(c.name)) p[c.name] = 0;
   p[c.name]++;

   return p;
}, {});
```

Comment: Nope that not work with this input :( : const topicsSort = [{"id":2,"name":"Health","color":"0190fe"},{"id":3,"name":"Agriculture","color":"0190fe"},{"id":1,"name":"Urban planning","color":"0190fe"},{"id":1,"name":"Urban planning","color":"0190fe"}]

Comment: @julian - I am getting `{Health: 1, Agriculture: 1, Urban planning: 2}` for the output - is that not right?

Comment: Yes, that's the exit I'd like to take :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm half exppecting someone to close this as a duplicate because all you've asked for is a frequency counter. But here's an answer anyway:

```
const jsonToIterate = *'MyPreviousInputJson'*;
const names = {};

jsonToIterate.map(obj => {
  if(obj.name in names){
    names[obj.name]++
  }
  else{
    names[obj.name] = 1;
  }
})
```

Comment: It’d be better to use `forEach` instead of `map` here, since you’re not using the array it returns. Also, `names` should be initialized to `Object.create(null)` if you’re going to use `in` with it, since objects inheriting from `Object.prototype` already have properties and will break if the input conflicts with them (like `"toString"`, `"valueOf"`, `"__proto__"`, etc.).

Comment: I thought about the `forEach` and `map`comparison for a while when writing that answer and I just couldn't make you my mind. And my role of thumb is `when in doubt, map`. But I guess you're right about it. But you're definitely right about initializing the object.